# C# lock keyword, I think I'm using this wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, locking

I recently had a problem with multiple form posting in an `ASP.NET MVC` application. The situation was basically, if someone intentionally hammered the submit button, they could force data to be posted multiple times despite validation logic (both server and client side) that was intended to prohibit this. This occurred because their posts would go through before the `Transaction.Commit()` method could run on the initial request (this is all done in nHibernate)

The MVC ActionMethod looked kind of like this..

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModelObject model)
{
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
 {
  // ...

  var member = membershipRepository.GetMember(User.Identity.Name);
  // do stuff with member
  // update member
 }
}
```

There were a lot of solutions proposed, but I found the C# `lock` statement, and gave it a try, so I altered my code to look like this...

```
public ActionResult Create(ViewModelObject model)
{
 if(ModelState.IsValid)
 {
  // ...
  var member = membershipRepository.GetMember(User.Identity.Name);
  lock(member) {     
     // do stuff with member
     // update member
  }
 }
}
```

It worked! None of my testers can reproduce the bug, anymore! We've been hammering away at it for over a day and no one can find any flaw. But I'm not all that experienced with this keyword. I looked it up again to get clarification...

> The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock

Okay, that makes sense. Here is my question.

### This was too easy

This solution seemed simple, straightforward, clear, efficient, and clean. It was **way** too simple. I know better than to think something that complicated has that simple a solution. So I wanted to ask more experienced programmers ...

### Is there something bad going on I should be aware of?

Comment: Isn't that `lock(someObject)` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was distracted when I typed it up. I've updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not that easy. Locking only works if the same **instance** is used.

This will not work:

```
public IActionResult Submit(MyModel model)
{
    lock (model)
    {
       //will not block since each post generates it's own instance
    }
}
```

Your example **could** work. It all depends on if second-level caching is enabled in nhibernate (and thus returning the same user instance). Note that it will not prevent anything from being posted to the database, just that each post will be saved in sequence.

### Update

Another solution would be to add `return false;` to the submit button when it's being pressed. it will prevent the button from submitting the form multiple times.

Here is a jquery script that will fix the problem for you (it will go through all submit buttons and make sure that they will only submit once)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':submit').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
            alert('You have already clicked on submit, please be patient..');
            return false;
        }
        $this.addClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

Add it do you layout or to a javascript file.

### Update2

Note that the jquery code works in most cases, but remember that any user with a little bit of programming knowledge can use for instance `HttpWebRequest` to spam POSTs to your web server. It's not likely, but it could happen. The point I'm making is that you should not rely on client side code to handle problems since they can be circumvented.

Comment: +1 - there's also a danger that another page will update the member in the second-level cache *between requests*, if you don't lock access to member throughout the application. It's probably worth letting NHibernate handle this - see the NHibernate documentation on [Transactions and Concurrency](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-10-transactions-and/1nr4enxv3dpeq/13#).

Comment: The problem is actually happening server side. There is logic to prevent the double entry, but the logic cannot run until the database is updated to reflect that the first entry has gone through, and by the time that happens, nHibernate has already returned an instance of `Member` that existed before the database was updated, and so the data still gets pushed through.

Comment: I know that the problem happens server side. The client code could prevent that, since the server will only be hit when the button is pressed the first time. My second update is in most cases not a problem. If an user really wants to screw things up for you, there are worse things to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's that easy, but be careful what object you lock on. It should be the same one for all the threads - for example, it could be a static object.
`lock` is syntactic sugar for a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf5de04k%28v=VS.90%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28LOCK_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), so there is quite a bit going on under the cover.

Also, you should keep an eye out for [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) - they can happen when you lock on two or more objects.

Comment: I guess I am just concerned that this 'solution' might have dire consequences down the line. It just seemed too simple, and too obvious. If it was that easy, why didn't anyone suggest it before? Why don't I see it in more code? See where my paranoia is coming from? As a programmer, I've learned that when something looks too simple, it probably isn't covering as many bases as you think it is.

Comment: Honestly I haven't understood your situation very well, but if you are sure that you need a certain piece of code be accessed by only one thread at a time, then `lock` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's that easy, but - there may be a performance hit.  Remember that a Monitor lock restricts that code to be run by only one thread at a time. There is a new thread for each HTTP Request, so that means only one of those requests at any given time can access that code.  If it's a long running procedure, or a lot of people are trying to access that part of the site at the same time - you might start to sluggish responses.

Comment: So I should really start to look for a different solution to this problem?

Comment: That might be the best course of action - as unless you really want only one Web Site user at a time to use this part of the code (which I don't think you do from your description ) this isn't the best solution.  What you might want to do is consider some javascript to hide to the button after it's been pressed so they don't hit the button a billion times resubmitting the form.